# Vectorization of complicated matrix calculation in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vectorization, numba

I have a 3x3 matrix which I can calculate as follows

```py
    e_matrix = np.array([m[i]*m[j]-n[i]*n[j] for i in range(3) for j in range(3)])
```

where `m` and `n` are both length-3 vectors. This works ok ✅

Now suppose that `m` and `n` are matrices of shape `(K,3)`. I want to do an analogous calculation to the above and get an `e_matrix` of shape `(3,3,K)`.

I realise I can just do a naive approach e.g.

```py
e_matrix = np.zeros((3,3,K))

for k in range(K):
    e_matrix[:,:,k] = np.array([m[k,i]*m[k,j]-n[k,i]*n[k,j] for i in range(3) for j in range(3)])
```

Does a vectorized approach exist? Ideally one that works with Numba/JIT compiling (so no e.g. `np.tensordot`).

Comment: returning (k,3,3) may be easier.  View `k` as a leading 'batch' dimension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the "vectorized" variation using numba.

```py
import numpy as np
import numba


@numba.guvectorize("(k),(k)->(k,k)", nopython=True)
def nb_vec_impl(m, n, out):
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            out[i, j] = m[i] * m[j] - n[i] * n[j]


def nb_vec(m, n):
    K = len(m)
    e_matrix = np.zeros((3, 3, K))  # Notice the position of K.
    # The matrix you want is (3,3,K), but this function accepts (K,3,3).
    # Instead of transposing the results, the same thing can be done by passing a transposed buffer.
    nb_vec_impl(m, n, e_matrix.T)
    return e_matrix
```

This function is fast when K is very large (e.g., 100,000), but, unfortunately, very slow when K is small due to the large overhead.

If performance is your priority, I would prefer a simple jit function.

```py
import numpy as np
import numba


@numba.njit
def nb_jit(m, n):
    K = len(m)
    e_matrix = np.zeros((3, 3, K))

    for k in range(K):
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                e_matrix[i, j, k] = m[k, i] * m[k, j] - n[k, i] * n[k, j]

    return e_matrix
```

Benchmark:

```py
import timeit

import numba
import numpy as np


def native(m, n):
    K = len(m)
    e_matrix = np.zeros((3, 3, K))

    for k in range(K):
        e_matrix[:, :, k] = np.array([[m[k, i] * m[k, j] - n[k, i] * n[k, j] for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)])

    return e_matrix


def broadcast(m, n):
    m, n = m.T, n.T
    return m[:, None] * m[None, :] - n[:, None] * n[None, :]


@numba.njit
def broadcast_nb(m, n):
    m, n = m.T, n.T
    return m[:, None] * m[None, :] - n[:, None] * n[None, :]


@numba.njit
def func2(m, n):
    m, n = m.T, n.T
    x, y = m.shape
    return m.reshape(x, 1, y) * m.reshape(1, x, y) - n.reshape(1, x, y) * n.reshape(x, 1, y)


@numba.njit
def nb_jit(m, n):
    K = len(m)
    e_matrix = np.zeros((3, 3, K))

    for k in range(K):
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                e_matrix[i, j, k] = m[k, i] * m[k, j] - n[k, i] * n[k, j]

    return e_matrix


@numba.guvectorize("(k),(k)->(k,k)", nopython=True)
def nb_vec_impl(m, n, out):
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            out[i, j] = m[i] * m[j] - n[i] * n[j]


def nb_vec(m, n):
    K = len(m)
    e_matrix = np.zeros((3, 3, K))
    nb_vec_impl(m, n, e_matrix.T)  # numba can accept transposed arrays.
    return e_matrix


def main():
    rng = np.random.default_rng(0)
    K = 100_000
    # K = 100
    m = rng.random((K, 3))
    n = rng.random((K, 3))

    candidates = [native, broadcast, broadcast_nb, func2, nb_jit, nb_vec]

    expected = native(m, n)
    # expected = broadcast(m, n)

    for f in candidates:
        assert np.array_equal(f(m, n), expected), f"{f.__name__}"
        n_run = 10
        elapsed = timeit.timeit(lambda: f(m, n), number=n_run) / n_run
        print(f"{f.__name__}: {elapsed * 1000:.3f} ms")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Results (for K = 100_000):

```
native: 778.374 ms
broadcast: 13.581 ms
broadcast_nb: 2.848 ms
func2: 6.207 ms
nb_jit: 1.998 ms
nb_vec: 1.891 ms
```

Results (for K = 100):

```
native: 0.798 ms
broadcast: 0.016 ms
broadcast_nb: 0.004 ms
func2: 0.007 ms
nb_jit: 0.002 ms
nb_vec: 0.127 ms
```

Answer (score 4):

Typically in raw numpy via [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
K = 4
m = np.random.rand(K, 3)
n = np.random.rand(K, 3)

# Shapes become (3, K)
m, n = m.T, n.T

# Shapes become:
# (3, 1, K)
# (1, 3, K)
# ========= *
# (3, 3, K)
out = m[:, None] * m[None, :] - n[:, None] * n[None, :]
```

I'm assuming this is numba compatible, but I'm not familiar...

Comment: This is a great answer. Unfortunately not numba/jit compatible, but might be sufficiently fast without.

Answer (score 2):

You can make [Chrysophylaxs' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77319870/15456681) compatible with numba (< 0.57) njit by changing the `[:, None]`'s... to use `ndarray.reshape()` instead as this is [supported by numba](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/numpysupported.html):

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

K = 4
m = np.random.rand(K, 3)
n = np.random.rand(K, 3)

m, n = m.T, n.T

def func(m, n):
    return m[:, None] * m[None, :] - n[:, None] * n[None, :]


@nb.njit
def func2(m, n):
    assert m.shape == n.shape
    x, y = m.shape
    return m.reshape(x, 1, y) * m.reshape(1, x, y) - n.reshape(
        1, x, y
    ) * n.reshape(x, 1, y)


assert np.array_equal(func(m, n), func2(m, n))
%timeit func(m, n)
%timeit func2(m, n)
```

Output:

```
3.02 µs ± 50 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
661 ns ± 7.64 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```