# Large performance difference between indexing and reshape in numba

Tags: python, numpy, performance, numba

In numba >= 0.57 we can now add axes to arrays by indexing with `None` whereas previously this would have raised:

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function(<built-in function getitem>) found for signature:
 
 >>> getitem(array(float64, 2d, F), Tuple(slice<a:b>, none))
```

so I would've used reshape instead as this was supported. I have noticed though that there is a large difference in performance between using indexing with `None` and reshape, and was wondering what explains this?
Consider the following code, in which the times with pure numpy are the same but the indexing method is ~2x faster than reshape with numba:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb


K = 4000
m = np.random.rand(K, 3)
n = np.random.rand(K, 3)

m, n = m.T, n.T

def func(m, n):
    return m[:, None] * m[None, :] - n[:, None] * n[None, :]

def func2(m, n):
    assert m.shape == n.shape
    x, y = m.shape
    return m.reshape(x, 1, y) * m.reshape(1, x, y) - n.reshape(
        1, x, y
    ) * n.reshape(x, 1, y)
    

func_nb = nb.njit(func)
func2_nb = nb.njit(func2)

assert np.allclose(func(m, n), func_nb(m, n))
assert np.allclose(func(m, n), func2_nb(m, n))
assert np.allclose(func2(m, n), func2_nb(m, n))
    
    
%timeit func(m, n)
%timeit func2(m, n)
%timeit func_nb(m, n)
%timeit func2_nb(m, n)
```

Output:

```
227 µs ± 2.58 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
226 µs ± 610 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
49.9 µs ± 268 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
96.6 µs ± 166 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Comment: looking at `func2_nb.inspect_types()` suggests that Numba doesn't perform `reshape` optimally.  not sure why it's allowed if it's effectively just calling out to Python code in `njit` mode.  note the performance difference is much more visible when `func = lambda m: 1*m[None, :]` and `func2 = lambda m: 1*m.reshape(1, *m.shape)`

Comment: There may be more than just one issue. For vomparison a simple tripple loop without reshaping is about 2 times faster than func_nb and 4 times faster than func2_nb.

Comment: @max9111 yes there are faster ways to solve this problem, it is copied from the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77319805/15456681).

Comment: @max9111 the current code likely creates temporary arrays which are quite expensive (they need to be allocated, written, read again and freed not to mention possible issue with page fault and typing). This is why a loop is indeed far better (looping is often better in Numba).